# Visual Studio 2017 - WIndows Forms - HTTP Post

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, post

I'm writing my first program ever and have everything working except running an HTTP Post command that tells our ticketing system "hey there's a new scan file to take a look at".  The app basically says pick your scan results file, enter your user ID and upload file.  That all works and the file is uploaded to our system under the correct client based on the ID provided.

I need to add  a HTTP Post section to my code that provides the following information:

```
POST /v4_6_release/apis/3.0/service/tickets HTTP/1.1
Host: login.mycompany.com
Authorization: Basic changedforthispost==
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: changedforthispost




{
    "summary":"A results summary has been uploaded",
    "company": { "id": 2 }
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What layer and technology is this; Web front end (mvc/asp), server backend (mvc, console, windows service)? If it is the backend, then you probably want to look at [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: So my app is just a windows forms app with some VB code in it.  The server that the post is going to is a ConnectWise ticketing system.  I'm not really sure what they use on that end.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
    Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
    Dim request As New HttpRequestMessage With {
        .RequestUri = New Uri("v4_6_release/apis/3.0/service/tickets"),
        .Method = HttpMethod.Post
    }
    request.Headers.Authorization = New Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("basic", "changedforthispost==")
    request.Content = New StringContent("{""summary"":""A results summary has been uploaded"", ""company"": {""id"": 2 }}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    Dim result As HttpResponseMessage = client.SendAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```

Construct an HttpClient, set the authorization header, and then set the content (you'll probably want to use Json.Net to create it).

Comment: My guess is that the `postman-token` comes from a tool called [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and isn't needed.